# SQL Server 2008 View Columns match to underlying Table Columns

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I've been attempting to write some SQL code that when provided with a view will locate the columns that the view columns reference and work out if there are any indexes on those columns.  The end aim is to provide users with a list of columns it would be possible to use when querying the view.

Currently though I can only find the columns that the view uses (and by extension their indexes) but I cant match them back to the index's columns.

For example:

I have `TableA`, which has 5 Columns: `ID`, `Name`, `Val1`, `Val2`, `TableBID`

I have `TableB`, which has 3 Columns: `ID`, `Name`, `Code`

I then create a view, `View1`, which is:

```
SELECT A.ID,
Name,
Val1
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB ON A.TableBID = B.ID
WHERE B.Code = 'AAA'
```

When I query for references using:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.View1', 'OBJECT')
```

I'll get a list of the Table/Column references within it, but no indication of which View Column references what.

Is there any way I can access the information I need, bear in mind I cannot do name matching as the columns in the Alias may use aliases and therefore may not have the same names as the underlying data.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 SP1 if that has any impact.

Comment: end users shouldn't be concerned with indexes

Comment: If "the end aim is to provide users with a list of columns it would be possible to use when querying the view", then just display all columns.  There doesn't have to be an index on a field to query against it.

Comment: Its intended for an admin interface for users with particularly high permissions, columns can be marked as "Searchable" but the default values for this state would be determined by the presence of an index.  It works for tables, but for views as I cant match view's aliased columns to their underlying table column, I cant work out if there is an index there or not.

I probably didn't explain it great but this functionality is intended for allowing a queries where clause to be generated. To lessen the chance of a slow SQL statement being generated by guiding users towards using indexed columns.

Answer (score -1):

Rename columns in view using unique combination **Tablename + '_' + ColumnName** for every view column. Then you can split views column onto table and column.